# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wrapper

Tags: python, flask

If I use 3.25.0 of Flask-JWT-Extended, everything is fine but when I use the latest version I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__main__.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(as_module=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 848, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 305, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 392, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/workspaces/HejBE/src/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from api import auth, user, channel, call, connection, expert, accounting  # noqa: F401,E402
  File "/workspaces/HejBE/src/api/user.py", line 23, in <module>
    def get_user_details(user_id):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1315, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1282, in add_url_rule
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wrapper
```

Is a function named wrapper is conflicting with another one? I don't have such a function/endpoint in my app and some other packages I use are as:

- pip
- wheel
- Flask
- Flask-JWT-Extended==4.0.2
- SQLAlchemy
- Flask_SQLAlchemy
- Flask_Migrate
- alembic
- pytz
- google-api-python-client
- gevent
- pytest
- pytest-cov
- firebase-admin
- psycopg2-binary
- boto3

Why?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example which demonstrates the error you are seeing.

Comment: @vimalloc I just create an app with these packages and when try to run it with ``` python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 ```` I get the above error. What else details are needed?

Comment: A minimal, complete, and verifiable example. You aren't providing any code, just a stacktrace which is not super helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to carefully read the 4.0.0 breaking changes and upgrade guide: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v4_upgrade_guide/.

You probably missed something in there, such as still using `@jwt_required` instead of `@jwt_required()`